# Citizenship Status

Tags: usa, citizenship

I am a permanent resident. Recently I was doing research about how to get my citizenship. I found some informations on uscis.gov saying that someone might already be a US citizen if the person who petition for you is a citizen and you entered the US under 18 years old.  My dad is a citizen, he petition for me and I was under 18 when I came to the US. Now my question is, am I a US citizen even if I'm currently using my  green card? Please tell me how do I find out?

Comment: What is your date of birth?

Comment: When did that happen?

Answer (score 4):

If, at any moment in time on or after February 27, 2001, you were 1) a permanent resident (doesn't matter how you became a permanent resident), 2) under 18, and 3) living in the U.S. under the custody of a U.S. citizen parent, then at that moment you automatically became a U.S. citizen, even if you didn't know it.

[Here is an official reference](http://www.uscis.gov/policymanual/HTML/PolicyManual-Volume12-PartH-Chapter4.html)

Comment: This looks like a good answer. Could you add a link to an official reference that explains this?

Comment: @GregHewgill: added